# Redirecting in PHP

Tags: php, filter

I currently have this small include to reach a filter on the left side of the page. I have however created a second filter for a different purpose. It's a real estate website. On one page I want the filter to show properties for housing, on the other page I want it to display office/company property filter options.

This is what I currently have:

```
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
   <?php include_once(VIEW_PATH . '/includes/filter.makelaars.php'); ?>
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
            <div class="aanbod_rightside"
```

I have created a second php file (filter.bedrijfsaanbod.php) to make sure the filter options are different. How can I make sure I trigger that filter on the other page?

Comment: So this code is in your header which all pages use? And you want the include_once link to be different depending on what the current page is? Is that what you mean? If that is the case then a simple if else statement would suffice.

Comment: This code is placed in object.overview.php - that page in particular shows all placed "houses" or "company" buildings with a filter on the left side. I will try your fix, didn't think of it yet!

Comment: OK check my answer. That is how I would do it based on what I think the format of your site is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then something like this should do it. Where you have a variable $category that changes for each one. So in your other pages that include object.overview.php they set $category to be "houses" or "offices" or whatever you like.

```
<?php
if ($category == "houses") {
    include_once(VIEW_PATH . '/includes/filter.makelaars.php');
} else {
    include_once(VIEW_PATH . '/includes/filter.bedrijfsaanbod.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: No problem, enjoy the power of if statements :)